# Will a block run on a parent module run before code in the child module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

Consider an angular app like so (written on my phone, sorry for weird syntax):

```
angular.module('app1').controller(ctrl1, function($http){
    $http.get(...);
});

angular.module('app2', ['app1']).run(function($http){
    $http.default.headers.common.foo = 'bar';
});
```

Is the run block guaranteed to run before the controller code? In other words, if I load my page by calling app2, will I be guaranteed that all HTTP calls will have the default header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, 'run' block will be invoked during run phase, which is before controller's initialization.

However, I'd recommend you to configure default headers on config phase via `$httpProvider.interceptors`:

```
app.factory('httpRequestInterceptor', function () {
    return {
        request: function (config) {
            config.headers['foo'] = 'bar';
            return config;
        }
    };
});

app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');
});
```

Comment: Why would interceptors be better? Seems like more code to do the same thing

Comment: @DavidGrinberg since config phase is made for configuration (which is what we are actually trying to do), and run could be useful to perform any kind of initialization after the objects instances registered, config is preferable. Also, during run phase you can use services, which means there is a chance to send a request **before** configuring default header. It can not happen if you configure it in `.config()`